# Integration custom tables with pas.plugin.sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, plone

I'm trying to integrate custom table for authentication and role into PAS.plugin.sqlalchemy.

After customisation model.py I did manage to get my user table schema as we have in existing user table. But  while installation of this pas, its create numbers tables inculding property table. Property table linked with user table through foreign key. I don't have any property table in existing scenario.

By seeing my trackback I can see while doing SQL fetch pas looks for users and property table as join query. we have data in our user (web_contact_auth) table but not in property table.

```
u'SELECT TOP 1 web_contact_auth.contact_number AS web
_contact_auth_contact_number, web_contact_auth.password AS web_contact_auth_pass
word, principals.id AS principals_id, principals.type AS principals_type, princi
pals.zope_id AS principals_zope_id, web_contact_auth.password_reset_token AS web
_contact_auth_password_reset_token, web_contact_auth.password_reset_expiry AS we
b_contact_auth_password_reset_expiry \nFROM principals JOIN web_contact_auth ON
principals.id = web_contact_auth.contact_number \nWHERE web_contact_auth.contact
_number = ?' ('admin',)
```

My questiones are:
how should I create data in property table ? Is there anyway that I can ignore property table and just fetch data from user table only.

Adavance Thanks your time for reading/reply.

Regards

*WEBBYFOX*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't activate that plugin.  I don't have a properties table.  In /acl_users/plugins/manage_active, `Properties Plugins`, I have `sql` as the last option. I don't see anything else obvious.